# How can I extract part of the path and pass it as parameter to all actions in Play Framework in java?

Tags: java, playframework

Our paths are something like:

- www.example.org/first/firstaction
- www.example.org/second/firstaction
- www.example.org/first/secondaction
- www.example.org/second/secondaction

We need to get the first part (first, second) of the path for all actions, manipulate it and pass it to the action. I dont want to make the manipulation in every action, so I'm looking for a better way.

Filters might be good, but Filters wrap the action after the action has been looked up by the router. So they are too late for me. Global.onRouteRequest might be better, but I don't understand how to pass parameters to the action neither how to pass to standard routing afterwards.

What would be the best way?

Comment: Which version of Play are you using? Using Global is discouraged in the newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

I switched to Action composition: Using an Action to manipulate the path prefix and pass it per ctx.args.put() to every action that is linked to it per annotation.

Comment: I had the same idea but stumbled over passing on the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a split, the '/' as the split:

```
String[] parts = url.split('/');
String first = parts[1]; // first
String second = parts[2]; // firstaction
```